# Vote close reason & list of reviewers

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

From time to time while reviewing close votes, I cast the final close vote. Let's say I choose Reason B for that. But it is the reason A which got majority of votes.

The question is put on hold and reason A is shown, but sometimes my profile name is also shown in list of reviewers (though I chose reason B) and sometimes not.

What is the condition to add/not add reviewer names?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally, when a question is closed, all voters are shown as closing the question for the majority reason, regardless of whether or not they voted for that reason.

But there is an exception.  If the majority reason is "Off-topic", then all of the specific off-topic reasons are listed, each with the user who cast that specific vote.

Here is an example with a standard close reason.  We do not know who voted for what, just the majority voted for "Unclear what you are asking"

[image]

And here is an off-topic close (the off-topic reasons are out of date, but it still illustrates the point)

[image]

Keep in mind that the specific off-topic reasons are all classified as "Off-Topic", so you only need a majority of all of the "off-topic" reasons combined.  This can make it more confusing when you have a non-unanimous majority in favor of off-topic.

For example, 2 votes for unclear, 3 votes for off-topic (split between 1 for "tool request", 1 for "belongs on Super User", and 1 custom close reason) will show up as follows:

- It will be closed as "Off-topic" with all 5 voters attached to off-topic
- It will then list the 2 standard "off-topic" reason, each attributed to the single user who voted for that reason.
- The user who voted with the custom reason will only be attributed to close voting in the comments.
- The 2 voters for "Unclear what you are asking" will also not be attributed to a more specific close reason.

Comment: I've seen a number of 3/2 splits like the one pictured, but I've never seen a 4/1 split that I can remember. Does that happen as well?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I don't remember a specific occurrence off the top of my head, but I'm sure I've seen it.  My understanding of the feature is it will always list the specific off-topic reasons when off-topic is the majority selection (custom close reasons are the only exception as they are only shown in the comments).  You can get 2/1 or 3/1 splits too if  non-Off-Topic votes were cast.

Comment: @psubsee2003, thank you for detailed explanation. i have probably confused myself :( sorry for delay, yesterday i run out of close votes and i wanted to double-check situation when 3 people for reason A and i chose reason B

Comment: Your analysis of the off-topic reason actually doesn't work that way. An off-topic sub-reason will only ever show in the list if at least 2 users (or a moderator) chose that reason, meaning a maximum of only 2 sub-reasons can ever show normally (using up 4 of the 5 total close votes).