# If I close as a duplicate question with 4 close votes it is closed with a wrong reason

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, close-reasons, dupehammer

I tried to close question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558693/compiling-a-fortran-code?noredirect=1 as a duplicate of [Undefined reference to 'main' when compiling a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753150/undefined-reference-to-main-when-compiling-a-module)

However, the question already had 4 close votes for a different reason. That reason was no longer applicable. I have the golden badge duplicate closing privileges for that tag, but I did edit the question tags before so the privilege did not kick in.

Should the question really be closed that way it is? Should my duplicate vote close towards a very different reason? The question now contains enough steps to reproduce the problem, so the close reason is not applicable.

Comment: There are cases AFAIK where your dupe hammer doesn't work, e.g. when the [fortran] tag was edited in later (by you) and wasn't there in the original version.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Which is the case here (it was originally tagged `python` and `fortran90`).

Comment: @gnat If duplicate, then http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310538/vote-close-reason-list-of-reviewers or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188688/when-is-the-list-of-the-users-who-selected-a-close-reason-shown/188706#188706  Why would I mention that I edited the tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gold-hammer works on current tags (as long as you are not the one who added tag - in part to avoid temptation to add your gold tag to insta-close). So since originally tag you have gold in was not on the question and you are the one who added the fortran tag you cast regular close-as-dup vote. See [It looks like the duplicate banner changed. How does it work now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268278/it-looks-like-the-duplicate-banner-changed-how-does-it-work-now/268281) (older behavior was to just look at original tag - [Gold duplicate power didn't work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272475/gold-duplicate-power-didnt-work/272476)).

Close votes are always majority - so 4 debugging vs. one duplicate votes lead to debugging close result. So end result is expected. See [Vote close reason & list of reviewers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310538/vote-close-reason-list-of-reviewers), [When is the list of the users who selected a close reason shown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188688/when-is-the-list-of-the-users-who-selected-a-close-reason-shown/188706#188706) (there is special case for off-topic but duplicate is not off-topic).

In general you may be able to coordinate re-open/close vote with some other gold-hammer user or SO close votes chat room.

In case of this particular question I don't think it worth an effort - in current state it does not look very searchable/useful for future visitors and current close reason is acceptable (not correct, but there is no need to re-open). Your call here - if you find question to be good enough to serve as sign-post - edit it in shape and coordinate closing for correct reason.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of majority voting. It probably indeed isn't worth the effort. It took a lot of effort already to guide the OP to provide the details.

Comment: @Kendra - thanks! Id did not know that - I've updated post with this information.